# How stop zsh from eating space before pipe symbol?

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

When I type a space followed by the pipe symbol `'|'` on the zsh command line, zsh eats the space, placing the pipe symbol directly up against the prior word. How do I stop it from doing that? I'm not sure about any possible stylistic conventions, but I like a space on both sides of the pipe symbol for readability. I'm using oh-my-zsh pretty much out of the box.

**Solution**

Based on mpy's answer below, I used the following solution:

By default, ZLE_REMOVE_SUFFIX_CHARS is undefined in zsh/ohmyzsh. When undefined, it acts as though it was:

```
ZLE_REMOVE_SUFFIX_CHARS=$' \t\n;&|'
```

I added the following definition to my ~/.zshrc:

```
ZLE_REMOVE_SUFFIX_CHARS=$' \t\n;&'
```

(all except pipe) and presto, perfect! problem gone.

Comment: first re-try doing this using `zsh -f` (to skip loading your configuration). You'll notice that zsh won't do that anymore. Then, you'll have to dig (most likely) into *oh-my-zsh* to figure out how it is causing that ;-)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I suppose you mean that when you `TAB` complete a command / filename a space is added automatically, but after pressing `|` it vanishes again.
Otherwise I can't reproduce that effect.

However, in that case the solution should be as simple as

```
ZLE_REMOVE_SUFFIX_CHARS=""
```

---

The explanation is a litly bit tricky, so I simply quote `man zshparam`

> `ZLE_REMOVE_SUFFIX_CHARS` / `ZLE_SPACE_SUFFIX_CHARS`
>                 These parameters are used by the line editor.  In certain circumstances suffixes (typically space or slash) added by 
>   the
>                 completion system will be removed automatically, either because the next editing command was not an insertable character,
>                 or because the character was marked as requiring the suffix to be removed.
>
> These variables can contain the sets of characters that will cause the suffix to be removed.  If  `ZLE_REMOVE_SUFFIX_CHARS`
>                 is  set,  those  characters  will cause the suffix to be removed; if `ZLE_SPACE_SUFFIX_CHARS` is set, those characters will
>                 cause the suffix to be removed and replaced by a space.
>
> If `ZLE_REMOVE_SUFFIX_CHARS` is not set, the default behaviour is equivalent to:
>
> ```
> ZLE_REMOVE_SUFFIX_CHARS=$' \t\n;&|'
> ```
>
> If `ZLE_REMOVE_SUFFIX_CHARS` is set but is empty, no characters have this behaviour.  `ZLE_SPACE_SUFFIX_CHARS`  takes  precedence, so that the following:
>
> ```
> ZLE_SPACE_SUFFIX_CHARS=$'&|'
> ```
>
> causes the characters `&` and `|` to remove the suffix but to replace it with a space.
>
> To  illustrate the difference, suppose that the option `AUTO_REMOVE_SLASH` is in effect and the directory DIR has just been
>                 completed, with an appended `/`, following which the user types `&`.  The default result is `DIR&`.   With  `ZLE_REMOVE_SUFFIX_CHARS` set but without including `&` the result is `DIR/&`.  With `ZLE_SPACE_SUFFIX_CHARS` set to include `&` the result
>                 is `DIR &`.
>
> Note that certain completions may provide their own suffix removal or replacement behaviour which  overrides  the  values
>                 described here.

Comment: Yes, I hadn't noticed that until you mentioned it, but it only happens after a tab-completion, thanks for the answer, this gives me what I need :)

Comment: This isn't really a fix.  Too many or too few.  Now I get multiple spaces instead of just one.